# What film are these medical beds from?

Tags: story-identification, object-identification

I've seen some pretty wild conspiracy theories about magical "med-beds" that can cure any disease but are being suppressed by governments.

These pictures were posted claiming to be photos of these amazing med-beds.

I wondered if they were from a science fiction film, especially with the displays and labels looking rather like LCARS from Star Trek.

Does anyone recognise them?  Of course, they could have been custom-made in a 3D modelling program, but a film also seems possible.

[image: The picture depicts a mostly white facility with blue tainted glass devices. The general tone gives a sci-fi vibe, whilst also making it look like a future themed medical facility. There seems to be beds and tanks, the former possibly reminding the design of some cryogenics bed, and the latter looking like the kind of tanks in which you would find test labs creatures floating in suspicious liquids in movies and such. There seems to be relatively thin white mechanical arms near the tanks and beds. Whether those are to assist in mundane tasks or to perform a surgery of any kind is left to our imagination.]

[image: Another picture depicting the white futuristic medical lab looking facility, from a different angle. We can see the same tanks as in the first picture. The "cryogenics like beds" are also visible, but now they are placed vertically against the wall, instead of being on the ground.]

[image: The last picture still has the white medical facility feeling to it. Unlike the others, its design look more like an operating room of some kind. The room is square with a big blue hued door to leave, visible in the background. There is some kind of floating blue toned bed in the middle, with an oval light above it. There is a white circle device on one side of the "bed"; maybe where the head would be if someone was to lay down on it. There is also 3 mechanical arms on each side. The same kind as on the first picture. They seem to be attached to the oval light platform above the bed, where black lines are visible; maybe the 3 arms are meant to be able to slide around the bed for convenience.]

One of them has the words "CRYO IV" on the side, so possibly some kind of cryogenic/stasis/suspended animation pods.  They don't seem to be from *Prometheus* or *Passengers*.

Comment: The last one reminds me of Elysium, but the background and the other pictures don't match, I think.

Comment: Now I want to see these "claims", just so I can laugh at them!  I don't want links, but what would one search for in order to encounter them?

Comment: Just claiming that these are "photos" immediately discredits any associated claims.

Comment: These are so obviously renders that I find it hard to understand how anyone could mistake them for anything else. And honestly, 2 seconds on Google image search gives you the actual origin of the images.

Comment: \*smacks forehead\* I realise now I meant to reverse-image-search them but forgot to.

Comment: @Corey I don't know, the low quality can fool untrained eyes into believing those look like actual places. The main giveaway would be how empty everything looks (no tools, no paperwork, no coffee, nothing, even on the desks). At least in my opinion.

Comment: @Clockwork Yep, no clutter, no smudges, no depth of field, zero lens distortion... that and the fact that humans don't actually build floating beds with transparent screens, that's just foolish waste of resources. This is clearly SF; humans just wouldn't build like this. I mean, come on, screens mounted at about mid-thigh level? It's pretty, but not practical.

Comment: @Corey To me, "no clutter" and "no smudges" would mean that its probably a film set. (Remember, most eyes ARE untrained)

Comment: Yeah, it's more obvious that it's CGI once you see the high-res originals.  The ones posted make it less obvious that it's CGI rather than a film set... though I was suspicious about the Generic Sci-fi Crates (there's only one of those in the pictures I included, but more in others).  Even a film set seems unlikely to go to the length of mocking up those rather than using normal ones or not bothering.

Comment: @PeterM The original YouTube video has disappeared now (along with the entire channel it was on), but searching for some combination of "Med-Beds" and "NESARA" might get you the general conspiracy theory that it was from.  The NESARA theory is... ambitious.  Some other conspiracy theories are more modest, and sometimes plausible.  The NESARA theory seems to think modest is for boring people.

Comment: A couple of years ago, I asked on skeptics.stackexchange.com if flat earth theory was some satiric joke. Well, it seems nothing is too crazy for the right followers.

Comment: The first thing the top picture reminded me of was the [surgery machines in the original game System Shock](https://shodan.fandom.com/wiki/Surgery_Machine).  Obviously memory is higher resolution than 90s games.

Comment: 6k views, this took off  :-D

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This is original artwork by an artist called [cermaka](https://www.turbosquid.com/Search/Artists/cermaka).

So, no, not from any film or secret government conspiracy.

[image: This picture looks very similar to the first picture of the question, with the beds and the tanks. The main difference is that the one from the question was fully rendered with colors and more or less realistic looking design, whereas this picture is raw: it's colorless, and you can see the lines of the 3D shapes/meshes.]

You can see his work [here](https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/3d-futuristic-laboratory-interior-scene-model/1043232?referral=cermaka):

[image: A screenshot showing some of the artworks of the original author. We can recognize some of the pictures from the question, as well as the design similarities in some other artworks.]

There is nothing to indicate that is movie concept-art either.

[image: Another screenshot showing some other artworks of the author, including the "surgical bed lookalike" from the question.]

The pictures (in the OP's question) all come from the single 'laboratory' 3d file, which was made in Autodesk 3ds Max and rendered in V-Ray. Made in 2017, you can buy it for around US$400.

Comment: Of course, if it *was* a government conspiracy, then maybe cermaka (and @blobbymcblobby) [are in on it...](https://giphy.com/gifs/the-x-files-l41lFptE01rEpCFQA)

Comment: *cough* ...i..er..

Comment: Come on now Mr. McBlobby, the correct response is "no comment" ...  you _obviously_ need government shadow operative retraining.

Comment: @CGCampbell the correct response is distinctly *not* "no comment", at least in general.

Comment: Isn't "not from a conspiracy" just what a conspirator would say? That's good enough proof for me.

Comment: It's very obviously a conspiracy. Posting it is artwork with no obvious purpose is a nefarious plan to slowly seed the possibility into the public's mind so that it can be revealed without culture shock at the moment of choosing.

Comment: Interesting marketing ploy.  "Buy our weird lab artwork and get this cool tank free". :-)

Comment: I love the way conspiracy theorists think (not.)  You have this top secret lab full of genius level people doing things far beyond state of the art in medical science and computer technology - and these same geniuses are so stupid that they let pictures of their over-the-top-secret equipment and labs get publicly posted to the internet.

Comment: @JRE - no, they deliberately leak the pictures to flaunt their power & untouchability, and then giggle about it all night long in an Illuminati coven. That's the exact answer I got from a moon hoaxer. It's the same irrefutable "logic" that the door gunner in "Full Metal Jacket" propounds: "Anyone who runs is a VC! Anyone who stands still is a well-disciplined VC!"

Comment: @fectin Perhaps ["I can neither confirm nor deny"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glomar_response) is more your speed?

Comment: Everyone knows that the guy on TurboSquid SCANNED the actual conspiracy super science devices, so that he could sell the 3D models for a few bucks.